# Sending a vCard via android application

Tags: android, vcf-vcard, android-mms

I would like to send a vCard via MMS (since SMS does not support file attachments..). I have read many answers about launching the messaging app with an intent ([Sending an MMS with a vCard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942434/send-vcard-file-string-via-whatsapp-or-mail-programmatically) for example) but I could not find a way to send the MMS directly from my application, without directing the user to the messaging application.

There are SEND_SMS, RECEIVE_SMS and RECEIVE_MMS permissions in the manifest but no SEND_MMS. So is there any workaround that can allow me to send a vCard to another phone number on new android versions directly from my app?

Comment: Maybe you can use [MMS library](https://github.com/klinker41/android-smsmms)

Answer (score 0):

Since MMS is a HTTP based request in Android all you need is the internet permission.

BUT since there is not MMS API (like there is for SMS) you would have to write everything on your own.

[Maybe have a look at this](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms).

Or you could just use an Intent and launch the native Messaging App.

Answer (score 0):

I thnk this can Help you

MMS is just a htttp-post request. You should perform the request using extra network feature :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2973016/2931489